# How can I tell if an ActiveRecord object will be destroyed before it actually is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Whenever I create, update, or destroy a model I need to send a notification to a front end app. When sending the message, I need to know if the record is a newly created record OR if the record has been deleted. To avoid duplication I'd prefer to handle all of this in a single ActiveRecord lifecycle hook (i.e. before_save, after_save, after_commit, etc).

My issue seems to be that in the `before_save` callback, `destroyed?` will return false when I am destroying the object, but if I use `after_commit` then `new_record?` will return false even if I just created the object.

Is there a way I can reliably identify:

1. if a record was or will be destroyed

and

2. if a record is or was a new record

at a single point in the objects lifecycle?

Comment: `before_save` is triggered right before you create or update a record (new one or existing one) with save, so why are you expecting `destroyed?` to be true inside the callback ? Same with `after_commit`, once you create, update, or destroy the record can't be a `new_record?`.

Comment: I understand the reasoning (and wouldn't expect anything different in these callbacks) I'm just wondering if there is a way to achieve what I'm trying to do (perhaps with methods other than `destroyed?` or `new_record?`).

Comment: Isn't something like `after_commit :new_record, on: :create`(record created) enough ? You can build or send the message inside the method `new_record` (no need to check if it's newly created) and you can add one for each of `:create` and `:update`. More here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit

Comment: @limekin that will work! I didn't know you could specify action for a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `after_commit` :

```
after_commit :new_record, on: :create
after_commit :update_record, on: :update
after_commit :destroy_record, on: destroy

private
  def new_record
    # Send or build message here.
  end
  def update_record
    # Send or build message here.
  end
  def destroy_record
    # Send or build message here.
  end
```